# List In React Zeroing Scroll Position A Upon Reordering (In Chrome 72.0, on Mac)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am seeing some weird behavior with list scroll position

In this fiddle, I have a simple React component that displays a list of 20 items, and then after 5 seconds, moves item 10 to the top of the list.

```
class List extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        done: false,
        items: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
      ]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setTimeout(this._update, 5000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className={ this.state.done ? 'done' : 'not_done' }>
        { this.state.items.map((x) => (
            <li 
            key={ `item_${ x }` } 
            className={ `item_${ x }` }
          >
            { x }
          </li>
        )) }
      </ul>
    )
  }

  _update = () => {
    console.log('_UPDARE')
    this.setState({
      done: true,
        items: [
        10,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
      ]
    })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5o2x4bvf/

If you scroll down so that Item 10 is visible within the viewport when the reordering occurs, then the scroll position resets to zero.

If Item 10 is not visible (whether the viewport is above or below it), then the scroll position is not zeroed, which is the intended behavior.

I am only noticing this in Chrome (72.0) and not in Firefox or Safari.

I did an alternate implementation in Vanilla JS, and this is not occurring: https://jsfiddle.net/47rscqdy/2/

I stepped through the code and found that React was doing a somewhat inefficient reordering. Instead of just moving item 10 to the front, it moves items 1-9 to just before item 11. This Vanilla JS SSCE demonstrates the issue
https://jsfiddle.net/t9hfsqyp/1/

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Peculiarly, this doesn't seem to occur if you don't use keys (which goes against best practice...) https://jsfiddle.net/2mdztpjy/

Answer (score 8):

Well, that was a rabbit hole!

Turns out, this is due to the Scroll Anchoring feature that Chrome introduced in version 56, which can be disabled on the container using this css:

```
overflow-anchor: none;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qcfk3hwr/

Comment: bruh, I almost gave up on a task after 2 days, regarding reordering elements and animation moving up the scroll and the user experience being shitty. THANKS!